# HTML errors not showing

Tags: php

I am trying to test PHP (7.2) HTML error reporting.

I have downloaded the *"Many HTML files"* archive from http://php.net/download-docs.php and unpacked it to:

```
/home/user/public_html/php/manual/php-chunked-xhtml/
```

In php.ini for apache I have set:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On

html_errors = On
docref_root = "/~user/php/manual/php-chunked-xhtml/"
docref_ext = .html
```

and restarted the apache service.

As a test I do:

```
printf();
```

Which yields:

> Warning:  printf() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   /home/user/public_html/test/err.php on line 10

… but it is not linked to the manual pages. Text only.

What am I doing wrong here? Should there not be a link to `printf()`?

---

Edit:

`phpinfo()` say settings are as in ini (above). I have also tried to move the manual to `/var/www/html/phpmanual`, but same result. I also added

```
ini_set("html_errors", true);
```

to the test file, but no change in result.

The manual is browseable.

---

As for what I expect. Per manual one have:

> html_errors boolean
>
> > If enabled, error messages will include HTML tags. The format for HTML errors produces clickable messages that direct the user to a page
> >     describing the error or function in causing the error. These
> >     references are affected by docref_root and docref_ext.
> >     If disabled, error message will be solely plain text.

Thought I would get a link to `printf()` as per example.

Comment: What are you asking actually?
You're getting an error as the function expects at least 1 parameter while you pass nothing?

Comment: Check phpinfo() if your php.ini really got the changes. Else [`ini_set("html_errors", true)`](http://php.net/ini_set) should work at runtime.

Comment: I can't get it to work either, strange. The error changes from text to HTML so `html_errors` itself clearly has an effect, but setting `docref_root` and `docref_ext` do not result in links.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: Looks like the error was not severe enough. This: `$fh = fopen('/non/existent/file')` gives HTML *with* link report … it looks kind of inconsistent, but guess there is an explanation ;)

Comment: Heh yep I just discovered the same thing, odd.

Comment: @AlexHowansky: Yeah. And typically of me to go down that kind of rabbit hole when I 1. really do not need to, and 2. have lots of other things to do. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK found it finally -- the HTML error messages don't include links for all possible errors. For example:

```
strcmp();
```

Generates the warning:

> Warning: strcmp() expects exactly 2 parameters, 0 given

But there is no link to the strcmp() function page, even though one exists in the documentation pack. (function.strcmp.html)

However, this code:

```
preg_match('/', null);
```

Also produces a warning:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match.html]: No ending delimiter '/' found

But this one does include the link. Not sure what the difference is, as they're both E_WARNING level messages and both have doc pages present.